# S3 S3EncryptionClient AWS SDK for PHP: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, aws-php-sdk

For my connection I am using Use the AWS shared credentials file default profile. I have .aws/credentials setup containing aws_access_key_id aws_secret_access_key. This works fine for localhost to S3 connectivity using S3Client.

However, I want to do client side encryption/decryption using S3EncryptionClient and here is where the problems start. Using PHP 3.6 and aws-sdk-php 3.5. I had to manually install Crypto directories since for whatever reason composer would not get them even though as far as I understand support was added in v3.38.

putObject following [Amazon S3 Client-Side Encryption with the AWS SDK for PHP Version 3 example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-encryption-client.html#encryption) fails with "Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server". I am using the same user, key, secret in both cases when using S3Client or when using S3EncryptionClient. I assume KmsMaterialsProvider does not require 'credentials' => $provider to be specified, but I have tried that as well.

Edit:
Tried the same in IAM Policy Simulator. Perhaps policy is not setup correctly. But not quite sure what is required. Tried a bunch of different variations without any success. Keep getting "denied   Implicitly denied (no matching statements)." for actions such as: Encrypt, Decrypt even though policy has these actions. Is the problem that I am doing this from my local machine? But then I would have thought it would fail the same way for non encrypted write/reads.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, in case anyone runs into the same issue as it looks like at least a few people did without an answer. Creating KmsClient on dev environment (localhost) needed to specify 'credentials' => $provider, even if already specified for S3EncryptionClient . Also make sure that permission policy is setup for the key and KMS service.